# Hierarchy repeating levels

Tags: ssas, hierarchy, cube

I am trying to create a very simple geographical hierarchy on a Carrier dimension. My data is something like this:

Carrier City State Country

```
Carrier A | Chicago | IL | USA
Carrier B | Aurora | IL | USA
Carrier C | Stockton | CA | USA
Carrier D | Winnipeg | MB | Canada
Carrier E | Richmond | BC | Canada
Carrier F | Valparaiso| ZAC| Mexico
Carrier G | Veracruz | VER |Mexioc
```

My Hierarchy is defined as

```
Country
State
City
Carrier
```

Attribute Relationships:

```
Carrier --> City Name --> State Name --> Country
```

I expected the browser to display the hierarchy as follows:

```
USA
IL
Chicago
Carrier A

Aurora
Carrier B
CA
Stockton
Carrier C

Canada
MB
Winnipeg
Carrier D

BC
Richmond
Carrier E

Mexico
ZAC 
Valparaiso
Carrier F

VER
Veracruz 
Carrier G
```

Instead it's repeating each level in the hierarchy:

```
USA
IL
Chicago
Carrier A

USA
IL
Aurora
Carrier B

USA
CA
Stockton
Carrier C

Canada
MB
Winnipeg
Carrier D

Canada
BC
Richmond
Carrier E

Mexico
ZAC 
Valparaiso
Carrier F

Mexico
VER
Veracruz 
Carrier G
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the same and everything is worked as expected:

```
create table Carrier (Carrier varchar(100),City  varchar(100),State varchar(100),Country varchar(100))

insert Carrier (Carrier,City,State,Country)
select 'Carrier A','Chicago','IL','USA' union all
select 'Carrier B','Aurora','IL','USA' union all
select 'Carrier C','Stockton','CA','USA' union all
select 'Carrier D','Winnipeg','MB','Canada' union all
select 'Carrier E','Richmond','BC','Canada' union all
select 'Carrier F','Valparaiso','ZAC','Mexico' union all
select 'Carrier G','Veracruz','VER','Mexico'
```

And SSAS structure:
[image: Carrier Hierarchy]

Please check next things:

1. Keys of each attribute, that used in hierarchy.
2. Relationships on the second tab.
3. SQL source table. Maybe there are some unprintable symbols or smth like that. And this was interpreted by server like different keys (If you use chars for keys, but it's better to use integers).